# Pandas merge and fill

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, fill

`portfolio_balance_dates_df.merge(historical_transfers_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)`

Right now I have this but it gets rid of any row that is not included in both dataframes. I want to merge and keep all of the rows and fill in the dates that are not in the `historical_transfers_df` as `0`.

Then I will use the new merged dataframe to subtract the balance if they are on the same day, to get the historical balance without bank transfers.

This is what `historical_transfers_df` looks like:

```
            historical transfers
2021-02-17  202.20
2021-02-14  71.27
2021-02-08  9967.89
...
```

This is what `portfolio_balance_dates_df` looks like:

```
            portfolio balance
2020-01-09  4.420000
2020-01-10  4.270000
... ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? Use an `outer` merge and `fillna` with 0:

```py
portfolio_balance_dates_df.merge(historical_transfers_df,
    how='outer',
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True,
).fillna(0)
```

```
            portfolio balance   historical transfers
2020-01-09  4.42                0.00
2020-01-10  4.27                0.00
2021-02-08  0.00                9967.89
2021-02-14  0.00                71.27
2021-02-17  0.00                202.20
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for. Thank you.